# How to add units like kg or grams 'superficially ' in a list in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

How can I add units to all of the contents of a list superficially?
Like this

```
list_without_units = [1,2,3]
list_with_units = [1'kg',2'kg',3'kg']
```

Please remember that I want to put the kg with the values just to show that they are in kilograms not that I want to make any calculations using kilograms.

Comment: `1'kg'` is wrong you can have `'1kg'`

Comment: What precisely do you mean by *"superficially"*?! Your proposed output is not valid syntax.

Comment: Even though you're not looking to do any computations, this might still be a good match: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/units/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a list comprehension for this.

```
list_without_units = [1,2,3]
list_with_units = [str(value)+"kg" for value in list_without_units]

print list_with_units # ['1kg', '2kg', '3kg']
```

with quotes around the kg unit the list comprehension looks like this:

```
list_with_units=[str(value)+"'kg'" for value in list_without_units]
# print result: ["1'kg'", "2'kg'", "3'kg'"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Other answers look good, You can also use `map` to convert each of them in the list.

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> map(lambda x:"{}kg".format(x) , l)
['1kg', '2kg', '3kg']
>>> map(lambda x:"{}'kg'".format(x) , l)
["1'kg'", "2'kg'", "3'kg'"]
```

Comment: good but note that `map` in less efficient than list comprehension!

Comment: also this might be a little (too) challenging for the OP.

Comment: @kasperTaeymans It is better to learn good methods at the starting itself! Hence I mentioned, *Other answers look good* and upvoted both of them

Comment: Upvoted your answer too. However I still belief that you first need to learn crawling before even attempt to run.

Comment: @kasperTaeymans LOL. :) Let's just assume that the OP is some superhero and he starts running even before he is delivered :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str` function to convert your int numbert to string then use `+` to concatenate the `kg` , in a list comprehension:

```
>>> [str(i)+"'kg" for i in list_without_units]
["1'kg", "2'kg", "3'kg"]
```

*Note* that if you want to use `'` as separator you need to put one quote inside double quote! else you can do the following :

```
>>> [str(i)+"kg" for i in list_without_units]
['1kg', '2kg', '3kg']
```

Comment: I think you meant `... str(i)+"'kg'" for ...` Note the extra `'`

Comment: @BhargavRao I thinks OP wants to use `'` as separator!